# CSS for mso classes in web project ASP.NET

Tags: html, css, asp.net, vb.net, ms-word

Here is my situation: people have been making documents in Word and pasting the text into a FreeTextBox control. This text is then saved to a SQL table, and shown on a screen at a later time. In a desktop version of this process, the data is displayed with all of the formatting the user created (tables, styles, etc). Now, this process has been moved to a web application - and while the data is still saved, and is displayed on the screen, things like table cell borders are no longer there. I noticed that the properties that Word uses on these cells are prefixed with **mso**-some-style-prop: some attribute;

MSO-anything isn't a valid attribute. How do I get the CSS to apply properly on a user control within a web project? I have looked for an extension with no luck, and I have tried to create a method that replaces these properties, but it is very tedious and time consuming. So, before I went down that route I wanted to check with the SO community to see if there is anything out there to help ease the struggles. Thanks in advance.

Examples of Microsoft styling:

```
<TABLE style="mso-cellspacing: 1.5pt; mso-yfti-tbllook: 1184; mso-padding-    alt: 0in 0in 0in 0in" class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellPadding=0>
```

Comment: Heh, good luck. That MS Office generated HTML is an absolute mess. You may have had the right idea to convert it to something more useful. Perhaps you could take that one step further and create an open source library that others could contribute to? Or look to see if a library already exists for this purpose?

Comment: Unfortunately (or fortunately), the route I have to take is looking more and more like creating a library.

Comment: Is this what you're using? - http://www.freetextbox.com/demos/everything.aspx , as it has a `Clean MS Word HTML` button - Just tested it with text from Word 2010, looks like it doesn't work.

Comment: That is what is being used. Sadly, it just eliminates all styling.

Comment: You could try another wysiwyg editor, tinymce for example - it has the functionality to strip MSO stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however; there are hundreds of documents that exist already. I am looking more for a post-processing solution.

Comment: Why the down vote? Would like to improve upon what went wrong with this post

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wanted to share the solution with you all. I ended up finding this link: http://blog.codinghorror.com/cleaning-words-nasty-html/

It takes care of the job pretty well. I had a problem with one of the regular expressions, but it served as a great starting point. Hope this will help someone.

This is what I used:

```
Public Module Parser

    Public Function Main(text As String) As String

        Dim html As String = ""
        'Console.WriteLine("input html is " + text.Length + " chars")
        html = CleanWordHtml(text)
        html = FixEntities(text)
        Return html
    End Function

    Private Function CleanWordHtml(html As String) As String


        Dim sc As New StringCollection()
        ' get rid of unnecessary tag spans (comments and title)
        sc.Add("<!--(w|W)+?-->")
        sc.Add("<title>(w|W)+?</title>")
        ' Get rid of classes and styles
        sc.Add("s?class=w+")
        sc.Add("s+style='[^']+'")
        ' Get rid of unnecessary tags - I was unable to get this regular expression to work working
        'sc.Add("<(meta|link|/?o:|/?style|/?div|/?std|/?head|/?html|body|/?body|/?span|![)[^>]*?>")
        'sc.Add("<(meta|link|/?o:|/?style|/?div|/?std|/?head|/?html|body|/?body|/?span|![)[^>]*?>")
        ' Get rid of empty paragraph tags
        sc.Add("(<[^>]+>)+&nbsp;(</w+>)+")
        ' remove bizarre v: element attached to <img> tag
        sc.Add("s+v:w+=""[^""]+""")
        ' remove extra lines
        sc.Add("(nr){2,}")
        For Each s As String In sc
            html = Regex.Replace(html, s, "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        Next
        Return html
    End Function
    Private Function FixEntities(html As String) As String
        Dim nvc As New NameValueCollection()
        nvc.Add("""", "&ldquo;")
        nvc.Add("""", "&rdquo;")
        nvc.Add("Ã¢â‚¬â€œ", "&mdash;")
        For Each key As String In nvc.Keys
            html = html.Replace(key, nvc(key))
        Next
        Return html
    End Function
End Module
```